# Operating on an array which is passed by reference to it's first element

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have this piece of code in separate Chromosome.cpp which is supposed to turn any double into binary with given precision and store it in an array:

```
char* Chromosome::convert()
{
double precision = CHROMOSOME_PRECISION;
int toconvert = (int)(value * (1.0 / precision));
char binary[CHROMOSOME_LENGTH] = { (toconvert < 0)?'1':'0' };
_itoa_s(toconvert, binary, 2);
printf("Value is: %i, binary representation is: %s\n", toconvert, binary);
    return &binary[0];
}
```

And then I want to operate on an created array, like for example swap halves of it (for example from 11110000 and 11001100 make 11111100 and 1100000). So I made another .cpp called Operations, where I will hold functions that will modify my chromosomes. But I have no idea what I should write inside function like that:

```
void cross(Chromosome a, Chromosome b)
{



}
```

I've tried things like char* aBinary[32] and then aBinary[0] = a.convert(); but it's not working...

Answer (score 2):

```
return &binary[0];
```

You're returning a pointer to a local array which is being destroyed.  Undefined behavior when the caller tries to use it.

You can either have the caller provide a buffer which `convert()` fills in, or have `convert()` perform dynamic allocation and require the caller to deallocate.

If using dynamic allocation, prefer an object that automatically manages the memory, such as `std::string`, `std::vector<char>`, or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` rather than a raw pointer.